# Чтение VM-свойства за пределами VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, проектирование

Имеется класс `Action`, который представляет собой некое действие. Это действие также может содержать коллекцию вложенных действий `ChildAction`.

```
public class Action
{
    public Action Parent {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Action> ChildActions {get;set;}
}
```

Класс `ProjectVM` представляет собой коллекцию действий `Action`:

```
public class ProjectVM : BaseVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Action> Actions {get;set;}
}
```

В `MainVM` есть свойство, которое хранит активный проект:

```
public class MainVM : BaseVM
{
    public ProjectVM SelectedProject{get;set;}
}
```

В интерфейсной части `ProjectVM` представлен `TreeView`, а коллекция `Actions` его элементами, которые можно перетаскивать и вкладывать друг в друга.

Drag&Drop реализован с помощью [GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop.](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop)

Мне нужно знать какой элемент куда был перенесен для формирования истории изменений (Undo/Redo) в каждом `ProjectVM`.

Но как в обработчиках `Drag&Drop` подцепиться к `SelectedProject` в рамках MVVM, которые находятся вне всей этой экосистемы и просто цепляются к контролам с помощью attached property?

```
<TreeView dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True"
          dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
          dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
          dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DropHandler}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}" />



public class DropHandler : IDropTarget
{
    //...
    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        //Здесь нужно взаимодействие с SelectedProject
    }
}
```

Можно, конечно, сделать свойство `SelectedProject` статическим, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это неправильно.

Может быть это вообще неправильный подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь мессенджером для передачи сообщений (читай -  инициирование событий) между Вашими VM. В коде обработчика drop - вызываете событие,  в нужной Вам модели это событие обрабатываете и сохраняете историю действий. 
 Для этой цели можете воспользоваться [event broker](http://www.appccelerate.com/eventbroker.html). Очень удобное API,  позволит Вам обеспечить низкий уровень связности между классами приложения.

```
public class DropInfoEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public IDropInfo DropInfo { get; private set; }


    public DropInfoEventArgs(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        this.DropInfo = dropInfo;
    }
}

public class MainVM
{
    private EventBroker broker;
    private List<DropHandler> dropPublishers;


    public MainVM()
    {
        this.broker = new EventBroker();
        this.dropPublishers = new List<DropHandler>();

        var dropPublisher = new DropHandler();
        this.dropPublishers.Add(dropPublisher);


        this.dropPublishers.ForEach(dp => this.broker.Register(dp));            
    }
}

public class DropHandler : IDropTarget
{
    [EventPublication("topic://ProjectVM/HasBeenDropped")]
    public event EventHandler DroppedEvent;

    public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        DroppedEvent(this, new DropInfoEventArgs(dropInfo));
    }
}

public class ProjectVM
{
    [EventSubscription("topic://ProjectVM/HasBeenDropped", typeof(OnPublisher))]
    public void DroppedEvent(object sender, DropInfoEventArgs e)
    {
        DropHandler eventSource = sender as DropHandler;
        IDropInfo info = e.DropInfo;
        //определяем, относится ли это события к нашему ProjectVM, 
        //если да, то выполняем нужные действия
    }
}
```

Comment: К слову, приведенная выше библиотека - это аналог известного [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) из Prism.

Comment: @klutch1991, Не могу понять как цепляется обработчик события из VM к самому событию. Не могли бы вы накидать небольшой пример?

Comment: обновил ответ..

Comment: @klutch1991, `DroppedEvent` всегда `null`. Видимо это из-за того, что сейчас в UserControl в конструкторе у меня создается экземпляр `DropHandler` и биндится к attached property. А получается, что нужно биндить к экземпляру, который зарегистрирован в `EventBroker`, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Не учёл, что EventBroker не может работать с параметризированными делегатами. Нужно добавлять собственный тип аргументов события. Тогда всё работает. Пересмотрите код.

Comment: Да, правильно, все объекты, работающие с событиями мессенджера, должны быть зарегистрированы в одном месте.

Comment: @klutch1991, Что-то у меня каша в голове :) Получается, что в таком случае нужно будет делать `DropHandler` свойством в `ProjectVM`, чтобы можно было биндить его в `UserControl`, а это ведь тоже как-то нелогично?

Comment: @klutch1991, Но, опять же, если мы делаем `DropHandler` свойством в VM, то зачем нам вообще использовать эту либу, ведь мы можем напрямую подписаться на события. Подскажите, где брешь в моих размышлениях?)

Comment: На события напрямую подписаться, конечно, можно, но особенность в том, что в MVVM для общения между ViewModel принято использовать Messenger. Самому писать это муторно и долгол, поэтому можно использовать бибилиотеки вроде той, которую я Вам предложил.

Comment: @klutch1991,И все-таки, как вы считаете, `DropHandler` здесь должен выглядеть как свойство `ProjectVM`?

Comment: Думаю,  что да. Либо можете поискать другую библиотеку,  которая будет выполнять drag drop

Comment: По сути, Вам нужно выбрать между агрегацией и наследованием. Если вы делаете Drop Handle свойством вашей VM, то это будет агрегацией. Возможно, более лаконично будет использовать наследование всех VM, которые будут использовать перетаскивание, от базовой VM, которая будет содержать событие и его обработчик.